# How can I test execution time of a query in C# .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2017.

I have a line of code like this:

```
EndIndex = TotalPages <= PageButtons ? TotalPages : 
Math.Max(PageButtons, Math.Min((PageIndex + pageRange), TotalPages));
```

How can I can compare this to alternate ways of writing this same code for a result, like:

```
AltEndIndex = TotalPages <= PageButtons ? TotalPages : (PageButtons > (PageIndex + pageRange) ? PageButtons : (TotalPages < (PageIndex + pageRange) ? TotalPages
                : PageIndex + pageRange));
```

I am about to test that they do actually give the same result, but regardless, there are probably 5 different ways to come to the same result, I am trying to figure out what method is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

[BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) is the golden standard for microbenchmarks such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stopwatch class to create a timer to check ticks.

[Stopwatch Code Reference and Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7)

Compare one function with the other and use what's faster for you. :)